# How do we improve our stats?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, beta-phase

Looking at our report card on Area 51, I see the following numbers today:

- 1.7 Questions/day
- 100% Answered
- 98 Avid users
- 1670 registered users
- 2.1 Answers/question
- 138 visits per day.

The first and last numbers are the most concerning. With 98 'Avid' users, that means we only see traffic from another 40 per day. I suspect few of those are new each day.

The low visits-per-day probably goes a long way to explaining the low questions count.

It's hard to imagine that, long term, these numbers support an ongoing investment in the site by SE Inc.

So, how do we improve them?

- Can we get links to the site on the home pages of FSF and OSI?
- Posting in the meta of other sites like Law, SO, etc to raise awareness as a migration target?
- What else?

Comment: Just a general FYI: Those stats have been obsolete for a while. Robert Cartaino has been trying to get them changed/modified/buried-in-an-unmarked-grave for some time now, but they remain up.

Comment: @HDE226868 do you mean that they are no longer relevant, or that they are no longer accurate?

Comment: @trichoplax No longer considered a good metric of a site's growth.

Comment: @trichoplax Looks like a bit of both, look at the 5k analytics privs now...

Answer (score 6):

Quite honestly, I wouldn't worry.

If you compare ourselves to other betas, I would think that we are doing fairly well.

- We have an incredible user base

  We're friendly and all, and we've got experience. We know what we're talking about, and we're willing to help others. Also, an "avid" user is basically just anyone with over 200 rep. :)
- We've got voting

  Many sites are falling victim to the "no voting" issue, such as eOS, and Law. As a result, the full community can't moderate effectively, they receive large amount of questions from new users, but only a handful can really look to them, and vote... We've got those users, and a lot of them.

We're slow, but we're ever going. I think we're going fairly well.

#### How do we improve?

By sharing.

Migration paths aren't even available anyway for beta sites, and all migrations have to be done through a moderator, anyway. It won't really help.

Instead, share it with your friends. We're trying to see if we can regain contact with the OSI now that we've got an established leadership here, and we're just waiting for the response on that.

---

About the stats, I've looked at the stats that are available to myself, and I've noticed a sort of trend. There seems to be a correlations between the number of questions asked, and the number of visits that the site receives (like a result of hot network questions). It seems to have been good for us, we get more users, and more visibility as that happens. We get roughly 150 visits a day, of which about a third are newcomers to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Arduino beta has a banner on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/:

[image]

IMO it would be great for beta site to exchange such banners with each other and with mature sites, to guide users towards the community which is the most relevant to their question.

Comment: Yes, these are community ads. We have such ads on various sites that are operating as well, and you can find our community ads post by searching with the [advertising] tag.